# Preciso que quando eu clicar no botão uma DataExtenssion é criada, porém meu código não esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho um código em SSJS que cria uma Data extension no Marketing Cloud porém eu não posso usar esse código no meu onclick event, descobri que AJAX poderia me ajudar mas ainda está dando erro   " Uncaught ReferenceError: DataExtension is not defined"

Segue o código :

```
<script>
    function ajax() {
     var xmlHttp;
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
     } else {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
     
       
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
  alert("status " + xmlHttp.status); alert("status " + xmlHttp.readyState) 
  console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)}
  xmlHttp.open('POST','https://....com', true)
  xmlHttp.send();
    }
</script> <script>
     
   
function create() {
   var DE = "MinhaDataExtension"
  var CustomerKey = "Teste123456"
    try {
        
      var obj = {
            "CustomerKey" :CustomerKey,
            "Name" : DE,
            "Fields" : [
                { "Name" : "Id", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : false },
                { "Name" : "MyData", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
                { "Name" : "Active", "FieldType" : "Boolean", "DefaultValue" : true }
            ] 
        }; } catch (err){ alert("(!) Data Extension was not created. Error message: " + err + "<br>")}
       
       DataExtension.Add(obj)
}        
  </script> 
  <button onclick="create();ajax()">
    Request 
     </button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Segue o código SSJS junto a um AJAX, para criar a Data extension dentro do Salesfoce Marketing Cloud a partir de um botão de dentro de uma Web Page

```
<script>
    function ajax() {
     var xmlHttp;
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest
     } else {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
     
       
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
  
  console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)}
  xmlHttp.open('POST','https:// your web page link', true)
  xmlHttp.send()}
    </script>


 <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1")
  var DE = "MyDataExtension"

    try {
        var obj = {
            "CustomerKey" : 1234CustumerKey,
            "Name" : DE,
            "Fields" : [
                { "Name" : "Id", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
                { "Name" : "MyData", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
                { "Name" : "Active", "FieldType" : "Boolean", "DefaultValue" : true }
            ]
        };
        DataExtension.Add(obj); 
    } catch (err) {
        
    }     
        </script> 
   
  <html>
  <button id="vamos" onclick="ajax();create()">
    Request 
     </button>
```